# Checking the class of a column in a function that uses tidy evaluation

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I am not referring to the column name as a string, but how can I check the class in the if statement when I am not referring to the column name as a string:

My problem is with the `if statement` bellow: I have tried `rlang::as_name`, `quote` etc.

```
df <- tibble::tibble( time_text = as.character(as.POSIXct("2018-02-03 08:00:00", tz = "UTC") + rnorm(100, 0, 60*60*60)))

date_from_text <- function(df, x){

  if(!class(df[[deparse(x)]]) %in% c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" )) {

  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  name <- rlang::quo_name(x)

 out <-  df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!name := lubridate::ymd_hms(!!x))
  }
  else {
    stop("Seems that column is in the right format already")
       }  
}

date_from_text(df, time_text)
 Error in deparse(x) : object 'time_text' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when you use the `x <- rlang::enquo(x)` and `name <- rlang::quo_name(x)` before the `if`-statement:

```r
date_from_text <- function(df, x){

  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  name <- rlang::quo_name(x)

  if(!inherits(df[[name]], c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))) {

    out <- dplyr::mutate(df, !!name := lubridate::ymd_hms(!!x))

  } else {

    stop("Seems that column is in the right format already")

  }  
}
```

I changed the requirement in the `if`-statement to `!inherits(df[[name]], c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))`.
In your original code only the first element of the class vector would be checked, whereas inherits checks if any of the specified classes is inherited.

```r
my.df <- tibble::tibble(time_text = as.character(as.POSIXct("2018-02-03 08:00:00", tz = "UTC") + rnorm(100, 0, 60*60*60)))

my.df2 <- date_from_text(my.df, time_text)
my.df2
# A tibble: 100 x 1
#   time_text          
#   <dttm>             
# 1 2018-02-06 18:38:46
# 2 2018-01-31 16:16:15
# 3 2018-02-04 05:52:32
# 4 2018-02-05 23:31:50
# 5 2018-02-06 13:00:34
# 6 2018-02-01 16:16:24
# 7 2018-02-05 15:09:45
# 8 2018-02-04 04:23:00
# 9 2018-02-03 06:55:18
# 10 2018-01-29 01:06:26
# ... with 90 more rows

date_from_text(my.df2, time_text)
```

> Error in date_from_text(my.df2, time_text) : 
>    Seems that column is in the right format already

Thanks to @KonradRudolph for improving this answer with his comments.

Comment: @kath: Thanks, but I think only ``name <- rlang::quo_name(x)`` is needed before the if statement, right? Actually I was just about to try this before your answer..

Comment: No you need both before, as `quo_name` expects a quosure or expression.

Comment: btw thanks for adding ``any`` if the ``if`` statement.

Comment: Same comment regarding `any` as for Ronak’s answer: The best way of comparing for class is via `inherits`, not with `class` and `%in%`.

Comment: @kath I don't know why my function does not return anything... I have changed the order of the if statements a bit...

Comment: @David You can explicitly state to return `out` by adding `return(out)` after you create that object. However, the function should return out invisible, that means if you assign the result of the function call to something (i.e. my.df2) you can check that object and it should contain the modified df.

Comment: @kath. It is not possible to check the class by subsetting with ``[[]]``, subsetting with ``[[]]`` always returns a data frame and thus the ``class`` will always to data frame.

Comment: @kath: my mistake, forget the last message.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the new curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)

date_from_text <- function(df, x){

  if (!class(df %>% pull({{x}})) %in% c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")) {

      x <- rlang::enquo(x)
      name <- rlang::quo_name(x)
      df %>% mutate(!!name := lubridate::ymd_hms({{x}}))

   } else {
     stop("Seems that column is in the right format already")
   }  
}

df1 <- date_from_text(df, time_text)

df1
# A tibble: 100 x 1
#   time_text              
#   <dttm>                 
# 1 2018-02-05 06:47:00.947
# 2 2018-02-06 13:25:36.656
# 3 2018-01-31 18:45:57.358
# 4 2018-02-05 02:16:56.179
# 5 2018-02-06 15:43:30.417
# 6 2018-02-07 14:59:56.203
# 7 2018-02-01 04:25:29.382
# 8 2018-01-31 19:11:13.136
# 9 2018-02-02 18:47:06.812
#10 2018-02-03 17:31:45.790
# … with 90 more rows

date_from_text(df1, time_text)
```

> Error in date_from_text(df1, time_text) : 
>     Seems that column is in the right format already

Comment: I’ve got to admit that I am getting lost in the operator precedence in this code … using a prefix call syntax for `class`, or alternatively parentheses, would make this clearer. Furthermore, the `all` doesn’t make sense in this code, since it will always be used with a single column.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Tried to make it cleaner. Hope it is readable now. I used `all` because `c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")` is a vector with length 2. So although it will be used on a single column it will return a vector of length 2 as well.

Comment: Much clearer, but you’re probably under-caffeinated because I’m sure you know that `x %in% y` returns a vector of the length of x, not of the length of y. That said, `class(x)` might of course be a vector of length > 1, which is incidentally why the recommended way of testing for a class isn’t `==` or `%in%` but `inherits` … So the proper way of writing this would probably be `data = pull(df, {{x}}); if (inherits(data, A) || inherits(data, B)) …`

Comment: @KonradRudolph ooops...missed that. You are right. Updated the answer, it also helped to reduce some more parenthesis and made it cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: what is the reason that the function does not return anything sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

or quote the column-name you want to check

```
date_from_text <- function(df, x){

  if( !class( df[[x]] ) %in% c( "POSIXct", "POSIXt" )) {
    df[[x]] <- lubridate::ymd_hms( df[[x]] )
    return( df[[x]] )
  }
  else {
    stop( "Seems that column is in the right format already" )
  }  

}

date_from_text( df, "time_text" )
```

Comment: I don’t think this is the solution OP is after, since they’re explicitly using rlang.